# Split and Join problems

Tags: c#, for-loop

I split them to get first letter to be upper case now I'm having problem merging them and the first letters are still upper cased. Also my data is from a database

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //input = input.Replace("_", "");
        string input;
        input = table_menu.Text;
        string[] words = input.Split('_');

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            string nword = word.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("", word.Skip(1));
            string merge = String.Join("", nword);
            MessageBox.Show(merge);
        }

        label1.Text = input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("", input.Skip(1));
        Console.WriteLine(label1.Text);       
    }
```

> Current Ouput: tablepatient

I want a out to be like this:

> TablePatient

Comment: You are replacing all your `_` with blanks, effectively removing them (the first line that is commented). Check out your `words` string[] in the debugger; i'm guessing it should contain just one element.

Answer (score 3):

The concept of capitalization is culture-specific - capitalization in one culture may not be the same as capitalization in another.  If you are serializing your strings to XML for persistent storage, you probably want to use the [invariant culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx); if you are showing them to a user, then the [local culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or maybe the [local UI culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) is appropriate.

That being said, [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) probably do the job:

```
        public static string UnderscoreToTitleCase(string input)
        {
            return UnderscoreToTitleCase(input, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }

        public static string UnderscoreToTitleCaseInvariant(string input)
        {
            return UnderscoreToTitleCase(input, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        public static string UnderscoreToTitleCase(string input, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            string[] words = input.Split('_');

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string word in words)
                sb.Append(cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(word));
            return (sb.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Nice... CultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase... one forgets always the simplest things :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string input;
     input = table_menu.Text;
     string[] words = input.Split('_');

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     foreach (string word in words)
     {
        string nword = word.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("", word.Skip(1));
        string merge = String.Join("", nword);
        MessageBox.Show(merge);
        sb.Append(nword);
     }

     label1.Text = sb.ToString();
     Console.WriteLine(label1.Text);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var input = "table_patient";

var output = String.Join("",
    input
        .Split('_')
        .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .Select(x => new string(
            x
                .Take(1)
                .Select(c => char.ToUpperInvariant(c))
                .Concat(x.Skip(1))
                .ToArray())));

//output == "TablePatient"
```

This also works:

```
var output = System
    .Globalization
    .CultureInfo
    .CurrentCulture
    .TextInfo
    .ToTitleCase(input)
    .Replace("_", "");
```